# Umbraco, FullTextSearch - including search of Media section?

Tags: umbraco

I have installed FullTextSearch (http://fulltextsearch.codeplex.com/) on my website and it is working good. Whatever keyword I type, FullTextSearch goes through content and tries to find that keyword.

But when I type some keyword which is only available in Media section in back-end of Umbraco, I can't find anything even with the fact that I have hunderds of files in Media folder??

Can anyone explain what is the issue and why FullTextSearch can't find anything from Media Section?

Many thanks in advance! Adi

Answer (score 4):

By default, Umbraco doesn't index media items. There's a plugin out there called [Cog Umbraco Examine Media Indexer](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/cogumbracoexaminemediaindexer) which adds an index for the media section of the site, and can index PDFs, Word and Excel files, text files, and other file types that the [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) project can parse.

If you take the Media Indexer approach, then you'll have to customize your search page to utilize both the Full Text Search and Media Indexer indexes. [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/36518-Combined-Examine-index-containing-media,-content,-members#comment132185) provides one approach for combining multiple search indexes. Note that the Media Indexer creates an index named "MediaIndexSet" and the Full Text Search plugin creates an index named "FullTextIndexer".

**EDIT**

Here's an example of how you can create a `MultiIndexSearcher` to combine the two search indexes:

```
var indexes = new[] {"FullTextIndexer", "MediaIndexer"};
var directories = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
foreach (var index in indexes)
{
    var indexer = ExamineManager.Instance.IndexProviderCollection[index];
    var directory =
        new DirectoryInfo(
            ((LuceneIndexer) indexer).LuceneIndexFolder.FullName.Replace("\\Index", ""));
    directories.Add(directory);
}

var searcher = new MultiIndexSearcher(directories, new StandardAnalyzer());
```

Then you can use the `searcher` object to perform your searching:

```
var criteria = searcher.CreateSearchCriteria();
var query = criteria.RawQuery("name:\"search terms\""); // Replace with actual query
var results = searcher.Search(query);
```

Comment: Hi cmptrgeekken, thank you very much for prompt reply! I have installed Cog Umb. Ex. I have an issue how to customize my search page (Full Text Search and Media Indexer indexes). I saw code you suugestted, made few combinations but no luck;( Can I send you link to my website to see how it works perhaps? Thanks,  MC2012

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide an example of how you can use the MultiIndexSearcher to search across the indices. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hi cmptrgeekken, I am currently trying to implement your code, I will let you know if it works out as soon as I get first results. BR, MC2012

Comment: Hi cmptrgeekken, I am trying to implement code you suggested but I have many issues;( I kidnly ask you to inform me if you could login to my website and help me withis, I will gladly pay fee you request because I really need to solve this asap. I hope you understand. Thank you, MC2012

Comment: @cmptrgeekken, would you happen to know where we can obtain the necessary dll binary to make Cog Umbraco Examin Media Indexer run?